# How do you mark spots when you work with the measure tool?

Tags: modeling, texturing, vertices, measurement, marker

[image]

Hello,
So I measured this spot with the measure tool and thats exactly where I wanna set a loop cut but as soon as I choose the loopcut tool the measured line dissaperas.. Is there a way to mark those spots?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a setting or anything, this is the way I "mark" the spot of my measure so I can loopcut it:

[image]

In solid preview mode, turn on X-ray and align the end of your measure to a reference line (in my case, line X.)

[image]

Next, go to loopcut mode and loopcut aligned with your reference line

[image]

The finale: A loopcut right on the end of your measure.